# ImportError: cannot import name 'json' from itsdangerous

Tags: python, docker, flask, docker-compose

I am trying to get a Flask and Docker application to work but when I try and run it using my `docker-compose up` command in my Visual Studio terminal, it gives me an ImportError called `ImportError: cannot import name 'json' from itsdangerous`. I have tried to look for possible solutions to this problem but as of right now there are not many on here or anywhere else. The only two solutions I could find are to change the current installation of MarkupSafe and itsdangerous to a higher version: https://serverfault.com/questions/1094062/from-itsdangerous-import-json-as-json-importerror-cannot-import-name-json-fr and another one on GitHub that tells me to essentially change the MarkUpSafe and itsdangerous installation again https://github.com/aws/aws-sam-cli/issues/3661, I have also tried to make a virtual environment named `veganetworkscriptenv` to install the packages but that has also failed as well. I am currently using Flask 2.0.0 and Docker 5.0.0 and the error occurs on line eight in vegamain.py.

Here is the full ImportError that I get when I try and run the program:

```
veganetworkscript-backend-1  | Traceback (most recent call last):
veganetworkscript-backend-1  |   File "/app/vegamain.py", line 8, in <module>
veganetworkscript-backend-1  |     from flask import Flask
veganetworkscript-backend-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/__init__.py", line 19, in <module>
veganetworkscript-backend-1  |     from . import json
veganetworkscript-backend-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/json/__init__.py", line 15, in <module>
veganetworkscript-backend-1  |     from itsdangerous import json as _json
veganetworkscript-backend-1  | ImportError: cannot import name 'json' from 'itsdangerous' (/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/itsdangerous/__init__.py)
veganetworkscript-backend-1 exited with code 1
```

Here are my requirements.txt, vegamain.py, Dockerfile, and docker-compose.yml files:

requirements.txt:

```
Flask==2.0.0
Flask-SQLAlchemy==2.4.4
SQLAlchemy==1.3.20
Flask-Migrate==2.5.3
Flask-Script==2.0.6
Flask-Cors==3.0.9
requests==2.25.0
mysqlclient==2.0.1
pika==1.1.0
wolframalpha==4.3.0
```

vegamain.py:

```
# Veganetwork (C) TetraSystemSolutions 2022
# all rights are reserved.  
# 
# Author: Trevor R. Blanchard Feb-19-2022-Jul-30-2022
#

# get our imports in order first
from flask import Flask # <-- error occurs here!!!

# start the application through flask.
app = Flask(__name__)

# if set to true will return only a "Hello World" string.
Debug = True

# start a route to the index part of the app in flask.
@app.route('/')
def index():
    if (Debug == True):
        return 'Hello World!'
    else:
        pass

# start the flask app here --->
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True, host='0.0.0.0')
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.9
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
WORKDIR /app
COPY requirements.txt /app/requirements.txt
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
COPY . /app
```

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3.8'
services:
  backend:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    command: 'python vegamain.py'
    ports:
      - 8004:5000
    volumes:
      - .:/app
    depends_on:
      - db

#  queue:
#    build:
#      context: .
#      dockerfile: Dockerfile
#    command: 'python -u consumer.py'
#    depends_on:
#      - db

  db:
    image: mysql:5.7.22
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: admin
      MYSQL_USER: root
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: root
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
    volumes:
      - .dbdata:/var/lib/mysql
    ports:
      - 33069:3306
```

How exactly can I fix this code? thank you!

Comment: All these methods propose fixing versions of flask or itsdangerous. While the release notes of the module propose to use Authlib [link](https://itsdangerous.palletsprojects.com/en/2.1.x/changes/#version-2-1-0). Since I think that is the cleaner solution, I would be interested in such a solution.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

I just put `itsdangerous==2.0.1` in my requirements.txt .Then updated my virtualenv using `pip install -r requirements.txt` and then `docker-compose up --build` . Now everything fine for me. Didnot upgrade the flask version.

Answer (score 69):

The import failure seems to be related with the latest release version of the package `itsdangerous`.
Check the latest releases [here](https://pypi.org/project/itsdangerous/#history)

In my case, I made it work by explicitly adding the package dependency `itsdangerous==2.0.1` in my `requirements.txt` file.

To make changes effective, update your virtual environment to reflect the new `requirements.txt`.

Comment: How would I update my virtual environment exactly, would I just use `pip install -r requirements.txt` or even `pip install -r requirements.txt --upgrade` inside of the virtual environment, or would I use another command similar to that one?

Comment: This worked for me and seems to be working on multiple versions of flask

Comment: worked for me too. It was breaking with `itsdangerous==2.1.0`

Comment: worked perfect for me, using python 3.9.5 and flask 1.1.2. Thanks @vinzee !!!

Comment: worked for me: python 3.9.2 and flask=2.2.2

Answer (score 23):

**Solution 1** - Upgrade the Flask to latest version i.e, 2.0.1 or above. It's the recommended way to fix the issue.

```
pip install Flask==2.0.1
```

OR

```
pip install Flask==2.1.0
```

**Solution 2** - Since it was difficult to upgrade to the latest version of Flask in a shorter time, you can try the below methods to resolve the issue.

you can continue using the Flask version 1.1.2 and try downgrading the itdangerous to 2.0.1. You can do this by adding `itsdangerous==2.0.1` to your requirements.txt file.

**Solution 3** - Another way is to upgrade Flask from 1.1.2 to 1.1.4 as it does not have groundbreaking changes and also downgrade the **markupsafe** library to 2.0.1

Once you upgrade from Flask 1.1.2 to 1.1.4 you will face another issue, which is [ImportError: cannot import name ‘soft_unicode’ from ‘markupsafe’ in Release 1.38.0 #3661](https://github.com/aws/aws-sam-cli/issues/3661), and that can be fixed by downgrading the markupsafe to version 2.0.1 as shown below.

```
pip install Flask==1.1.4
pip install markupsafe==2.0.1
```

Reference - [[Solved] ImportError: cannot import name ‘json’ from itsdangerous](https://itsmycode.com/importerror-cannot-import-name-json-from-itsdangerous/)

Comment: Yes, I have tried to do pip install Flask==2.0.1 and pip install itsdangerous==2.0.1, and pip install Flask==1.1.4 pip install markupsafe==2.0.1 as well as using my virtual environment to try and do all three steps but unfortunately, it still gives me the same error is there anything else I can do to fix this? thank you.

Comment: This is the only forward-looking solution (unpinning to upgrade the pinned obsoleted reverse dependency rather than pinning to make obsolete the latest dependency).

Answer (score 9):

Downgrade the ItstooDangerous to a lower version to support the flask.

```
pip3 install itsdangerous==2.0.1
```

Answer (score 5):

I was facing the same issue while running docker containers with flask.

I downgraded `Flask` to `1.1.4` and `markupsafe` to `2.0.1` which solved my issue.

Check [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/1094062/from-itsdangerous-import-json-as-json-importerror-cannot-import-name-json-fr) for reference.

Comment: Yes, I have already done that I have used `pip install Flask==1.1.4` and `pip install markupsafe==2.0.1` but that still does not work for some reason, thank you.

Answer (score 5):

The root of this issue appears to be that Flask 2.0.0 is unsupported. Try using the latest version of Flask.

https://github.com/pallets/itsdangerous/issues/289

As of March 8 2022, the latest version is 2.0.3:

```
pip install Flask=2.0.3
```

See [Flask source code on Github](https://github.com/pallets/flask/) for the most current version.

Comment: The latest version of Flask is 2.0.3 as of today, not 2.1.0

Comment: @Jon thanks for pointing that out. I edited the answer to have a date and a link to see the most current version.

Answer (score 5):

Adding `itsdangerous==2.0.1` to my `requirements.txt` file, and downgrading to `Flask==1.1.1` fixed it for me.

Comment: I have the same app in my Windows machine and cloud. adding isdangerous 2.0.1 fixed the issue for Linux system machine but still giving the same error on Windows. I am using Docker  in both cases. Any ideas why the issue does not disappear in Windows?

Comment: Try running " docker rm $(docker ps -a -q) -f " to remove all containers, verify you made the correct code changes, and spin it back up again.

Answer (score 3):

Running `pip install itsdangerous==2.0.1` in my virtual environment worked for me. Note: I'm using on my Windows 10 machine

Answer (score 1):

I uninstalled flask and reinstalled it:

- conda uninstall -c anaconda flask
- conda install -c anaconda flask

The following packages were installed: dataclasses-0.8, flask-2.0.3, itsdangerous-2.0.1 , werkzeug-2.0.3

Answer (score 1):

[image]

yep it seems itsdangerous decided to 'Import json from the standard library instead' from version 2.1.0 onwards https://itsdangerous.palletsprojects.com/en/2.1.x/changes/

So the following should resolve this particular error:
`pip install itsdangerous==2.0.1`

Answer (score -1):

This thread was useful for me too.

markup safe didn't quite swing it.

Itisdangerous=2.0.1 was the fifth on the list of my requirements, restored the passenger file, and smooth sailing from there!

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31422154)